# How to set a list index as the values within a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I have a nested listed called 'board', which is supposed to act like a 3x3 grid (this is for a TicTacToe program, I am a complete beginner):

```
board = [[' ', ' ', ' '], 
    [' ', ' ', ' '], 
    [' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

To access/change a single value in this nested listed I believe I would use two indexes, like so, in this case to change the very first value:

```
board[0][0] = 'X'
```

I don't want to have to input both coordinates to make a move, so I want to assign the numbers 1-9 a specific coordinate or location on the board, so it only takes one key press. I tried doing this with a dictionary:

```
dicBoard = {7: [0][0], 8: [0][1], 9: [0][2],
            4: [1][0], 5: [1][1], 6: [1][2], 
            1: [2][0], 2: [2][1], 3: [2][2]}
```

But that didn't work, calling for `print(dicBoard[7])` doesn't output [0][0] like I would want it to, but just 0. So if I try to target a specific value using `board[dicBoard[7] = 'X'` for example, the computer reads it as `board[0]` instead of `board[0][0]`, meaning it targets the entire first row of the list.

I also tried rewriting the dictionary as `dicBoard = {7: board[0][0]...}` and so on, but that doesn't work because I can't change any value in the original list 'board' through a single input in the dictionary. `dicBoard[7] = 'X'` doesn't change `board[0][0]` to 'X', it just changes the value in the dictionary itself.

**The reason I can't just use a dictionary and get rid of the list is because the way I am checking for three X's or O's in a row requires a '2D' list with coordinates, and I don't think I can assign coordinates to a dictionary. There's obviously different ways to check for a win using dictionaries, but I'm trying to do this without hardcoding every combination of TicTacToe.**

I am probably overcomplicating myself, but this isn't anything really serious it's just for me to learn and I'd rather take the challenge of understanding how to do this dictionary + list stuff.

:) Thanks

Comment: why are you using dictionary what is the problem with list access like `board[x][y]`?

Comment: @komatiraju032 because I only want to have a single input, instead of inputting x and y, I want to input z and have z already = [x][y]. I don't know if a dictionary is the best way to do that though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tuple here.

```
>>> dict_board = {7: (0,0), 8: (0,1), 9: (0,2),
                  4: (1,0), 5: (1,1), 6: (1,2),
                  1: (2,0), 2: (2,1), 3: (2,2)}

>>> dict_board(7)
(0,0)
```

Now you can take the `position_integer and value` as input from user. Now you can write your `if`, `elif` and `else` conditions to validate the entries.

Example: 7,1

Suggestion:

You wouldn't even require to consider [0][0] locations. You can ask the user to enter at the locations 1,2,3,...9 and maintain a dictionary {1: '0', 2: 'x',...9:'x'} and now you validate the tic

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using helper function of changing list using the indexes.
Modify your dictionary to store indexes as tuples.

```
dicBoard = {7: (0, 0), 8: (0, 1), 9: (0, 1),
            4: (1, 0), 5: (1, 1), 6: (1, 2), 
            1: (2, 0), 2: (2, 1), 3: (2, 2)}
```

And you can write a function to update value in list using dictionary

```
def set_value(idx, val):
    if idx in dicBoard:
        i, j = dicBoard.get(idx)
        board[i][j] = val
```

You can set the value by calling the method `set_value(move_number, value)` passing the two arguments.

```
set_value(7, 'X')
```